# ctags and tagbar with javascript

Tags: javascript, vim, ctags, tagbar

I installed tagbar in vim.

It parses the whole js file perfectly. 
But, when i try to use ctags, it doesnt parse the file well.

Now, isnt tagbar using ctags?

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/dVQuETMxHXqTEgM7Zeim1dMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `tags` and `pwd` status:

```
:set tags?
:pwd
```

The tags files shown by the `set tags?` command should be reachable from your `pwd`.

Comment: i tried :set tags?

It gave me tags=./tags, ./TAGS, tags, TAGS.

The ~/tags file contains the tags information, so i guess that map to the ./tags file outputted by the :set tags? command. the rest - ./TAGS, tags, TAGS - are none existent.

Comment: ohh yea, and when i try to do :tag /draw, it tell me there are 26 tags for draw. i dont know if it means 26 references and definition or just 26 definitions.

Comment: `ctags` deals with definitions only. You are supposed to use `cscope` for usage. Please, answer clearly to these questions: 0. What is your working directory (`:pwd`)? 1. Is it the same as the one containing `myjs.js`? 2. Do you have a `tags` file at the root of the working directory or at the root of the directory where `myjs.js` resides? 3. How and why did you `set tags` that way?

Comment: Also, depending on how you write your JavaScript or how `ctags` is configured it _may_ record tags in a dotted format like `constructor.method` in such a case `:tag method` won't work, only `:tag constructor.method` or `:tag /method` would do. It looks like you have a single `tags` file for all your stuff; if that's correct, it means that you have 26 definitions containing the word `draw`.

Comment: 0)the working directory is ~. 1)it is the same as the one containing myjs.js. 2) i dont understand very well what do you mean "the root of a directory". But the tags file is in ~ - thats the pwd and the directory that contains myjs.js. 3) i did not set the tags. I discovered it hehe ;)

Comment: so the updated goal is (i guess) how to make vim use the ~/tags file only (and not those none existent files). This will, hopefully, solve the original problem: i cannot get vim to use ctags properly. Even though, tagbar seems to be able to generate all the tags from my javascript file with no problem

Comment: OK, as I said in my answer, TagBar and Vim don't use the same mechanism at all. Both use `ctags` but Vim uses your `tags` file and TagBar uses `ctags` output directly. The only way to make both Vim and TagBar use the same `tags` file would be to rewrite a substantial part of TagBar which seems to be overkill, I think. It will probably be a lot more efficient to learn how to use both tools according to their respective strength.

Answer (score 0):

TagBar generates its own `tags` on the fly and it doesn't even write it to disk somewhere: ctags' output is directly parsed and displayed in the window.

You may get this error because you didn't generate a tags file with `:!ctags -R .` or because it's out of date.